# Android - Can't update the activity ProgressDialog from custom AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have created a custom AsyncTask class named ConnectionHttp. Which have to return a Json String, when called by a button in the main activity (test1.java). Everything is okay for the connection and I can get the string.

The point is that I want to display a ProgressDialog on the main activity while the background task is runing but it does not work. i don't see any ProgressDialog.

1) How can i fix the progressDialog

2) How can i solve the problem in logs (the application may be doing too much work ...)  (I'm testing on a real device)

Here is my code :

#### test1.java (main activity)

> public class test1 {
>
> ```
>  public static final String URL = ".....";
> private ProgressDialog pDialog;
> private TextView tv;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);
>
>
>     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(test1.this);
>     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
>
>     Button btRun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btTestRun);
>     btRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             try {
>                 ConnectionHttp conn = new ConnectionHttp(test1.this, pDialog, URL);
>
>                 String str = conn.execute().get();
>                 tv.setText(str);
>
>             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             } catch (ExecutionException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

#### ConnectionHttp.java

> public class ConnectionHttp extends AsyncTask
>   {
>
> ```
> private ProgressDialog pDialog;
> private Context context;
> private String LOGIN_URL;
> private JSONParser jsonParser;
>
> // TAGS
> private final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
> private final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
> private final String TAG_VALUES = "values";
>
> public ConnectionHttp(Context context, ProgressDialog pDialog, String url) {
>     this.context = context;
>     this.pDialog = pDialog;
>     this.LOGIN_URL = url;
>     this.jsonParser = new JSONParser();
> }
>
>
>
> @Override
> public void onPreExecute() {
>     super.onPreExecute();
>     pDialog.setMessage("Connexion au serveur distant...");
>     pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>     pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>     pDialog.show();
> }
>
> @Override
> public String doInBackground(String... args) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     int success;
>     String values = "";
>     try {
>
>         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
>         // adding parameters
>         //  ...
>         params.add(.....);
>
>          //
>
>         Log.d("request #1", "starting");
>
>         JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
>
>         // success tag for json
>         success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>         if (success == 1) {
>             Log.d("request #1", "Successfull");
>             values =  json.getString(TAG_VALUES);
>             return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
>         }else{
>
>             return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
>
>         }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     return values;
> }
>
> public void onPostExecute(String message) {
>     Log.d("request #1", "done.");
>     pDialog.setMessage("done.");
>     pDialog.dismiss();
> }
> ```

#### Android logs

> D/request #1﹕ starting
>
> D/request #1 : Successfull !
>
> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> D/request #1﹕ done

Comment: To solve problem that the application may be doing too much work Change String str = conn.execute().get(); to String str = conn.execute();
and just pass context to asynctask class and create ProgressDialog there.

Comment: It works when i change :
 `String str = conn.execute().get();`
to 
 `conn.execute();`

I created the ProgressDialog in the the AsyncTask class. and now it works but how can i get the Json String whitout the "conn.execute().get()"
? 
Thank you

Comment: You should use callback method, which will be called after async task completes and it will update your text view or use broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont pass progress dialog to the Async class. Instead create it on the Async class.

Modify **onPreExecute** to this

```
@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),"","Connexion au serveur distant...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();
}
```

Delete progress dialog from test1.java

Answer (score 0):

first remove your progress dialog from AsyncTask and use your passed context to create ProgressDialog;

```
public ConnectionHttp(Context context, ProgressDialog pDialog, String url) {
this.context = context;
this.pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
this.LOGIN_URL = url;
this.jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}
```